# How to initialise variables of returning tuple in c++?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

I have a function xyz() which returns an `tuple<std::string, double>`.
When I call this function individually, I can do the following:

```
auto [tresh, loss] = xyz(i);
```

This results in no error, but if I want to use the xyz() function in an if else block, then I can not use the `tresh` and `loss` variables anymore in the following code. Example:

```
if (boolX) {
        auto [tresh, loss] = xyz(i);
    } else {
        auto [tresh, loss] = xyz(j);
    }
std::cout << tresh << std::endl;
```

I also tried to initialise the tresh and loss variable before the if else block and remove the `auto`, but this gives the following error:

`Expected body of lambda expression`

How to resolve this?

Comment: Do you know something about scopes of variables? Your need using std::tie.

Comment: Just declare `tresh, loss` outside the `if`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before structured bindings were created, [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) was the solution for unpacking tuples.

```
std::string tresh;
double loss;
if (boolX) {
    std::tie(tresh, loss) = xyz(i);
} else {
    std::tie(tresh, loss) = xyz(i);
}
std::cout << tresh << std::endl;
```

It was considered clunky, because you have to declare variables before initialization, but that's exactly what you want here.

Comment: [`std::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore) can even be used: `std::tie(tresh, std::ignore) = xyz(i);`

Comment: *"but that's exactly what you want here"* - More like "that's what you settle for here".

Answer (score 11):

Depending on the exact code, you could replace with a ternary

```
auto [tresh, loss] = boolX ? xyz(a) : xyz(b);
std::cout << tresh << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or even `auto [tresh, loss] = xyz(boolX ? a : b);`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a lambda for it:

```
auto [tresh, loss] = [&boolX, &i, &j](){
    if (boolX) {
        return xyz(i);
    } else {
        return xyz(j);
    }
}();
std::cout << tresh << std::endl;
```

Comment: I hate when someone uses lambda this way. This should be just defined a a function.

Comment: @MarekR It's your opinion. I wouldn't define a function for this and you will find this style in different companies.

Comment: Yes it is my opinion, that is why I've wrote "I hate". I stumbled on this patter many times and it always made code harder tor read and harder to reuse repeating parts.

Comment: @MarekR You stumbled because you are used to old style code. People started learning C++ with e.g. C++14 or C++17 or people coming from other languages are used to this style. It's very common in JavaScript.

Comment: As any tools, they might be misused. I saw people abused of lambda: they repeat the same lambda over and over whereas it might be a function (or even a named (global) lambda). Here `loss` seems unneeded, making that construct strange IMO.

Comment: @Jarod42 It think it's clear that the lambda could also return `tresh` only. But since OP used structured binding in the question I want to stay with the behavior. OP could also use `xyz(i).first` if `loss` is unneeded. Also the condition in the question makes no sense. The same function with same argument is called in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
std::tuple<std::string, double> results;
if (boolX) {
    results = xyz(i);
}
else {
    results = xyz(j);
}
auto [tresh, loss] = results;
std::cout << tresh << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the two variables outside of the individual cases to access them outside. You can use `std::tie` to "tie" the two together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
std::tuple<std::string,double> xyz() { return {"foo",1.0}; }

int main() {
    std::string a;
    double b;
    bool condition = false;
    if (condition) {
        std::tie(a,b) = xyz();
    } else {
        std::tie(a,b) = xyz();
    }
    std::cout << a << " " << b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might restructure you code, so you do the job in its branch:

```
if (boolX) {
    auto [tresh, std::ignore] = xyz(i);
    std::cout << tresh << std::endl;
} else {
    auto [tresh, std::ignore] = xyz(j);
    std::cout << tresh << std::endl;
}
```

You might argue than code is longer, so make an extra function or lambda:

```
const auto do_job = [](auto&& p)
{
    auto [tresh, std::ignore] = p;
    std::cout << tresh << std::endl;
}
if (boolX) {
    do_job(xyz(i));
} else {
    do_job(xyz(j));
}
```